# SQL/ORACLE query excercise 18c

Tags: sql, oracle

Display, in alphabetical order, the actors who have played at least one film per year between 1980 and 1985

- FILM (CODFILM, TITLE, YEAR, GENRE) --Year is NUMBER, it contains only the Year
- ACTOR (CODACTOR,NAME,SURNAME,NAZIONALITY)
- CAST (CODFILM,CODACTOR, COMPENSATION)

I'm not sure about this solution, can someone check them?

```
SELECT *
FROM ACTOR
WHERE CODACTOR IN (
SELECT CODACTOR
FROM FILM NATURAL JOIN CAST
WHERE YEAR = 1980 AND YEAR = 1981 AND YEAR = 1982 AND YEAR = 1983 AND YEAR = 1984 AND YEAR = 1985)
ORDER BY COGNOME;
```

Another solution that I thought was (changing WHERE in the subquery):

```
WHERE YEAR BETWEEN 1980 AND 1985
```

Comment: Alright, I will do it, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must join all the tables, group by actor and set the condition in the having clause:

```
SELECT a.CODACTOR, a.SURNAME, a.NAME
FROM ACTOR a 
INNER JOIN CAST c ON c.CODACTOR = a.CODACTOR
INNER JOIN FILM f ON f.CODFILM = c.CODFILM
WHERE f.YEAR BETWEEN 1980 AND 1985
GROUP BY a.CODACTOR, a.NAME, a.SURNAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT f.YEAR) = 1985 - 1980 + 1
ORDER BY a.SURNAME, a.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes I use JOIN. What are the differences between JOIN and INNER JOIN?

Comment: Just JOIN is the same as INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Uomolepre, While `JOIN` AND `INNER JOIN` are the same (So it comes down to developer preference).  I still specify `INNER` so that I can quickly differentiate between `INNER`, `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `FULL`, and (very, very, rarely) `CROSS` joins.  Take a look at the `SELECT` documentation for more info. ([12c Documentation Link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABHEICD))